# Shadowing default method of an interface

Tags: java, java-8, default-method

Consider the following case,

```
interface IFace1 {
    default void printHello() {
        System.out.println("IFace1");
    }
}

interface IFace2 {
    void printHello();
} 

public class Test implements IFace1, IFace2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.printHello();

        IFace1 iface1 = new Test();
        iface1.printHello();

        IFace2 iface2 = new Test();
        iface2.printHello();
    }

    @Override
    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

In above example I am getting following output which is *quite* expected.

```
Test
Test
Test
```

I have been reading about `Java-8` default methods and *specifically* about [Extending Interfaces That Contain Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

> 2<sup>nd</sup> bullet : Redeclare the default method, which makes it abstract.

In above example where I have two interfaces which have default method with same name and when I implemented both I was only able to reach to the implementation of `printHello` of `Test` which refers to `IFace2`.

I have few questions about this,

1. How can I *reach* to the `printHello` method  of `IFace1` *and* if I can't than why ?
2. Doesn't this behavior keep me away from the intended nature of `IFace1` which is *may be* now shadowed by other method ?

---

Quote says, you can make the `default` method `abstract` in it's child interface. *For example,*

```
interface IFace2 extends IFace1 {
    void printHello();
}
```

Here when I implement `IFace2` I won't be actually able to reach `default` method of `IFace1` that is exactly what is happening in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are a bit confused by the presence of a `default` method. So let’s forget for a moment that `IFace1.printHello()` is a `default` method. So then, there is a clear situation: `Test` implements two interfaces, `IFace1` and `IFace2`, which happen to have a method with the same name and signature.

`Test` implements that method and therefore implements the method for both interfaces. The new feature of `default` methods does not change anything about this logic. Moreover, the language designers took care that adding a `default` method does not affect the behavior of existing code, so if your class implements the method, the presence of `default` methods becomes irrelevant.

However, if you write code that is aware of the presence of `default` methods, you may invoke it, if it is declared or inherited by a direct super interface, i.e. in your code you may use `IFace1.super.printHello()` to invoke the `default` method of `IFace1`.

The rules are not much different to the rules of super classes. If you change the interfaces so that interface `IFace2` extends `IFace1` and still declares `printHello()` as an `abstract` method, then this `abstract` method does override the `default` method and you can’t invoke `IFace1.super.printHello()` from within `Test` anymore.

As said, these rules are not much different to ordinary instance methods. If `Test` declares a method `printHello()`, that’s the *only* method that you can invoke by a reference to a `Test` instance, regardless whether its declared type is `Test`, `IFace1` or `IFace2`. Only implementation methods of `Test` itself may do `super` invocations.

---

The main difference comes into play when the possible multiple inheritance of interfaces is involved. If your class `Test` does *not* implement the method `printHello()`, it depends on the inheritance relationship of the two interfaces, what will happen

- If `IFace2` extends `IFace1`, it’s abstract method redeclares the `default` method, hence a compiler error occurs, as `Test` must implement the `abstract` method
- If `IFace2` does not extend `IFace1`, there are ambiguously two inheritable methods with the same name and signature, therefore `Test` will not inherit the `default` method, and a compiler error occurs, as `Test` must implement the `abstract` method
- If `IFace1` extends `IFace2`, `Test` will inherit the `default` method. It will also inherit it if `Test` does not implement `IFace2`, but this should come at a surprise…

Answer (score 5):

> How can I reach to the printHello method of IFace1 and if I can't than why ?

You can only do so within an instance method of a type that implements `IFace1` with

```
IFace1.super.printHello(); // only if IFace1 declares a default implementation of the method
```

In other words, you can't do it through a simple reference of type `IFace1` or `Test` (or whatever). That would break encapsulation.

> Doesn't this behavior keep me away from the intended nature of IFace1
>   which is may be now shadowed by other method ?

There's no shadowing going on here. You've overriden the method, so the overriden one gets invoked.

Concerning your 3rd question, you haven't extended any interfaces, so I don't see the relevance.

If you really did have

```
interface IFace2 extends IFace1 {
    void printHello();
}
```

with

```
public class Test implements IFace2 {
```

then you would not be able to access `IFace1`'s `default` implementation of the method. You can never skip super types to access implementations higher up in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @TAsk: `new Test().printHello()` will *always* invoke the method declared in `Test`, regardless of how you define the interfaces or whether `Test` implements them or not.

Comment: @TAsk I don't understand your confusion. Why do you expect anything other than the overriden method to be invoked?

Comment: @TAsk What do you mean by _meaningful_? If you don't override it in `Test`, your code won't compile.